Inline function with KClass from Swift in KMP
In KMP I have next EventBus
typealias Observer = (Any) -> Unit

object EventBus {
//// some code

    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    fun <T : Any> post(
        clazz: KClass<T>,
        event: T,
    ) {
        observers.value[clazz]?.forEach { it.invoke(event) }
    }

    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    inline fun <reified T : Any> post(event: T) {
        post(T::class, event)
    }
}

I try to launch post function from EventBus
        let event = LoadSuccessModel(message: "String")
        do {
            try EventBus.shared.post(event: event) }
        catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }

But I have error
`Error Domain=KotlinException Code=0 "unsupported call of reified inlined function `eventbus.EventBus.post`" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported call of reified inlined function `eventbus.EventBus.post`, KotlinException=kotlin.IllegalStateException: unsupported call of reified inlined function `eventbus.EventBus.post`, KotlinExceptionOrigin=}

I think something wrong in my code with KClass may be.
I try to look at swift-interopedia, but not find the answer how I need to change code.

Can you call the first overload, with a KClass parameter instead?

I'm not sure I understood what you mean correctly...

I mean just don’t call the inline function. Don’t you have another non-inline function that you can call?

Thanks @sweeper. Answer - dont call inline fun.
I changed my eventbus to use kotlin flow and call it in swift via async-await.
